# How do I remove/uninstall this security motion sensor?

Tags: lighting, motion-sensor

I have a security motion sensor that controls a pair of security lights. Unfortunately, the sensor has failed and I want to replace it.

For some reason, there doesn't appear to be a way to remove/uninstall or open it as there are no visible screws.

There is a seam down one side and I have inserted a flat-headed screwdriver in there to see if I can open it. Unfortunately, that just flexes the plastic. I do not want to be too rough and damage the eaves.

The brand of the sensor is Lanson (which is sold in Australia), but I was not able to find any installation instructions for it.

Here are some pictures of what it looks like:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flat blade screw driver and pop that little button off of the back side.  I strongly suspect that there is a screw under it that get you where you want to go. If that does not prove effective and you truly want to get rid of it use a straight claw hammer, get the claws between the base and the eves and simply pull it off carefully.